# Problem with newcommand and the optional argument

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I want to have a command that does the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\newcommand{\stuffing}[2][]{\ensuremath{W_{\mathtt{#2}}^{^{\left[#1\right]}}}}

\begin{document}
what I want: $W_\mathtt{a}$ and \stuffing[5]{a}

but what I get: \stuffing{a} and \stuffing[5]{a}
\end{document}
```

So, is there a way to include the brackets only when the optional argument is included? Or should I just make a new comment when the superscript is added? Since I cannot enter this: `\stuffing[\left[5\right]]{a}`

output of the example:

[image: output of example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to test whether the optional argument is empty or not:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\newcommand{\stuffing}[2][]{%
  W_{\mathtt{#2}}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    ^{^{[#1]}}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}
what I want: $W_\mathtt{a}$ and $\stuffing[5]{a}$

but what I get: $\stuffing{a}$ and $\stuffing[5]{a}$
\end{document}
```

I removed `\ensuremath` because that's math and so it should be properly segregated and you gain very little in not using `$...$` a few times.

[image]

With `xparse` you can use the `o` argument type:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\stuffing}{om}{%
  W_{\mathtt{#2}}%
  \IfValueT{#1}{^{^{[#1]}}}%
}

\begin{document}
what I want: $W_\mathtt{a}$ and $\stuffing[5]{a}$

but what I get: $\stuffing{a}$ and $\stuffing[5]{a}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello. What is the best method between xparse and etoolbox ?

Answer (score 3):

With `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\stuffing}[2][]{\ensuremath{W_{\mathtt{#2}}\ifblank{#1}{}{^{^{\left[#1\right]}}}}}

\begin{document}

what I want: $W_\mathtt{a}$ and \stuffing[5]{a}

and what I get: \stuffing{a} and \stuffing[5]{a}

\end{document}
```

[image]